# Different resolution for mirrored screen

Tags: macos, display, resolution, dual-screen

I'm using an intel MacBook Pro 16" 2019 with an LG 49WL95C Ultrawide Monitor connected by a single USB-C cable.

I'm trying to use a Lytmi Neo which is an ambilight device with light strips. It takes a HDMI input from the MacBook and outputs the HDMI to the monitor. I can't use HDMI as the monitor doesn't support 5120x1440@60Hz through HDMI. I figured I could instead continue to use the USB-C cable to the monitor and also use the HDMI cable input into the Lytmi Sync Box and then mirror the screens so that the sync box receives some input and can output the colours based on what's on the screen.

Now, mirroring means that a resolution of 5120x1440 is being outputted by the MacBook twice correct? And although performance is fine so far, it can lag slightly when resizing windows quickly or for other tasks. Is there any way to change the mirrored resolution to the device? I've tried using SwitchResX but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly as it doesn't seem to want to output different resolutions when mirroring so perhaps it doesn't offer the feature I'm looking for?

All I want is for the sync box to receive some input so that it can see the colours on the screen, whilst minimising the performance required from the MacBook as much as possible.